# Authentication Context error intent is not resolved

Tags: android, office365, adal

I am trying to authenticate an android appliction against an Azure Active Directory to validate users and eventually gain access to Office 365 hosted Sharepoint lists, using the sample codes [here](http://dev.office.com/Android#Auth-ADContext). But everytime I attempt to do so I get an `com.microsoft.aad.adal.AuthenticationException`: Activity is not resolved. Verify the activity name in your manifest file.

Is there something immediately obvious that I am doing wrong, or is there something that I am missing completely?

Here is my code for the `onCreate` method

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_dud);

  AuthenticationCallback < AuthenticationResult > callback = new AuthenticationCallback < AuthenticationResult > () {

    @
    Override
    public void onSuccess(AuthenticationResult result) {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      Log.d("Authentication Callback", "onSuccess");
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Success",
        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    @
    Override
    public void onError(Exception exc) {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      exc.printStackTrace();
      Log.d("Authentication Callback", "onError");
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error",
        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
  };
  try {
    ctx = new AuthenticationContext(DudActivity.this,
      "https://login.windows.net/mydomain.onmicrosoft.com", true);
    ctx.acquireToken(DudActivity.this, resource, clientId, redirectUri,
      PromptBehavior.Auto, callback);
  } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | NoSuchPaddingException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
  }

}
```

This is the log

> 03-13 13:08:10.025: E/AuthenticationContext(8980):
>   DEVELOPER_ACTIVITY_IS_NOT_RESOLVED:2015-03-13
>   12:08:10-99d5c2bb-f33a-4a47-8f16-b111e528617c-Intent is not resolved
>   ver:1.1.1  03-13 13:08:10.091: W/System.err(8980):
>   com.microsoft.aad.adal.AuthenticationException: Activity is not
>   resolved. Verify the activity name in your manifest file 03-13
>   13:08:10.092: W/System.err(8980):     at
>   com.microsoft.aad.adal.AuthenticationContext.localFlow(AuthenticationContext.java:1274)
>   03-13 13:08:10.092: W/System.err(8980):   at
>   com.microsoft.aad.adal.AuthenticationContext.acquireTokenAfterValidation(AuthenticationContext.java:1217)
>   03-13 13:08:10.092: W/System.err(8980):   at
>   com.microsoft.aad.adal.AuthenticationContext.acquireTokenLocalCall(AuthenticationContext.java:1119)
>   03-13 13:08:10.092: W/System.err(8980):   at
>   com.microsoft.aad.adal.AuthenticationContext.access$5(AuthenticationContext.java:1082)
>   03-13 13:08:10.092: W/System.err(8980):   at
>   com.microsoft.aad.adal.AuthenticationContext$4.call(AuthenticationContext.java:1068)
>   03-13 13:08:10.092: W/System.err(8980):   at
>   com.microsoft.aad.adal.AuthenticationContext$4.call(AuthenticationContext.java:1)
>   03-13 13:08:10.092: W/System.err(8980):   at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237) 03-13
>   13:08:10.092: W/System.err(8980):     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
>   03-13 13:08:10.092: W/System.err(8980):   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
>   03-13 13:08:10.092: W/System.err(8980):   at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818) 03-13 13:08:10.092:
>   D/Authentication Callback(8980): onError

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error is actually asking you to put activity in your manifest file. You can see the details at https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-android/blob/master/README.md

You need to have activity in your manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
  <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:debuggable="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <activity
            android:name="com.microsoft.aad.adal.AuthenticationActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_login_hello_app" >
        </activity>
  ....
  <application/>
```

You also need to implement onActivityResult so that adal can finish processing the result.

```
@Override
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
     super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
     if (mContext != null) {
         mContext.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
     }
 }
```

Comment: Yes!! Thank you it worked for me. I also noticed that there is an overload of the `acquireToken` method that does not require a context to be passed, that also worked for me.